Getting an error in erpnext frappe.cloud while calling server method in client script
Failed to get method for command frappe.core.doctype.B_Online_test.create_sales_invoice with No module named 'frappe.core.doctype.B_Online_test'
client script:
frappe.call({
    method: "define method here",
    args: {
        doctype: "Customer",
        filters: { "name": frm.doc.customer },
        fieldname: ["custom_fcm_token"]
    },
    callback: function(r) {
        if(r.message) {
            frm.set_value('order_status', 'Cancelled');
            send_fcm(frm,r.message.custom_fcm_token,"Order Status Updated","Your Order is Cancelled");
            frm.save();
        }
    }


Please arrange your question in readable format. try to include spaces and include code in code blocks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
